# EMV chip - Help finding how to add an antenna

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask a question like this.

I have this EMV chip that came off of  my tap to pay credit card. I am trying to put it on a ring I made, but the range is really low.

I heard that you can attach an antenna to it to increase the range but I’m not sure where to attach it. I have the original antenna it came with.

[image: EMV chip]

Comment: You would need to provide more information about the IC for most people to answer the question. Modifying the inductive antenna could also create problems for powering the chip as the inductive antenna also powers the chip.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but what does IC stand for, and what type of information would they need? The antenna I have was taken from the credit card it self so I don’t think it would cause a problem, but I could be wrong.

Comment: That is an antenna with an *Integrated Circuit* in the center.

Comment: Learn more about [integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit) here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. So it seems like if I try to modify it I can potentially break it. I am willing to try and modify it, I don’t know anything about the IC, all I do know is that it’s a tap to pay card from discover

Comment: This is a passive RFID chip.   It works by capturing external electromagnetic energy and using that to power itself.   The design of the "antenna" is critical - It's dialed-into the specific frequency used  - Very unlikely you'll make it better just by making it bigger.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification

Comment: NFC tags don’t like metal. At all. Trying to put that in or on a metal ring is bound to fail. You could trying adding a layer of ferrite between the chip and the ring, but it’s far from obvious it’ll work.

Comment: Does the shape of the antenna matter? 

The ring is printed from PLA plastic

Comment: did you succeed in your project ? I want to do the exact same thing with the exact same chip and same IC. (Very little info is available on the internet about these chips).